# telerik grid showing unwanted rows on slow system

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid

When the system is slow the telerik grid shows the 2 empty rows along with one row which contains "ready" text.Please suggest me how to resolve this.

Thanks,
Megha

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can hide your grid on load,

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("myGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.OrderID).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(o => o.ContactName).Width(200);
        columns.Bound(o => o.ShipAddress);
        columns.Bound(o => o.OrderDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Width(120);
    }).ClientEvents(events => events.OnDataBound("GridOnDataBound"))
......
......
).HtmlAttributes(new {style = "display: none"})
```

then using onDatabound event you can show your grid when the process finishes

```
<script>
    function GridOnDataBound() {
        $('#myGrid').show();
    }
</script>
```